# Trying to create treemap, getting error message about invalid column names

Tags: r, treemap

My code must be pretty close, but some small thing seems to be off.

```
library(treemap)

mydata = read.csv("C:\\path\\to\\files\\top_10.csv")

products <- unique(mydata$product, incomparables = FALSE)

treemap(mydata, #Your data frame object
        index=products,  #A list of your categorical variables
        vSize = reportable_amount,  #This is your quantitative variable
        type="index", #Type sets the organization and color scheme of your treemap
        palette = "Reds",  #Select your color palette from the RColorBrewer presets or make your own.
        title="TreeMap of Products and Amounts", #Customize your title
        fontsize.title = 14 #Change the font size of the title
        )
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Error in treemap(mydata, index = products, vSize = reportable_amount,  : 
  <index> contains invalid column names
```

My data set looks like this.

```
product asofdate    reportable_amount
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   29918501.83
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   50000000
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   40000000
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   13766666.67
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   75000000
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   40000000
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   9450000
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   91287458.38
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   -81498.17
CreditFacilities    3/30/2018   50000000
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -294715.28
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -304222.22
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -294715.28
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -275701.39
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -106689.44
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -285208.33
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -137850.69
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -275701.39
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -285208.33
DerivativePayables  3/30/2018   -147357.64
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   280264.06
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   144964.17
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   309256.89
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   289928.33
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   289928.33
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   299592.61
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   140132.03
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   37698.8
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   299592.61
DerivativeReceivables   3/30/2018   154628.44
```

I have one date, the product repeats several times, and there are 326 different records.

I got the idea from the link below, which I thought was pretty helpful.

https://rpubs.com/brandonkopp/creating-a-treemap-in-r

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in.

Comment: Can you list all the values of `products`? Are you sure that none of the values have illegal characters in them?

Comment: I posted a sample of data.  I know there are no special characters in the products names.  I had spaces originally; I got rid of those.

Comment: Couple things: 1) I'm confused about how this would become a treemap. Treemaps are generally for hierarchical structures--what hierarchy do you have here? 2) `vSize` in the docs says "name of the column in dtf that specifies the sizes of the rectangles. Required." You have negative values in the vector you gave to `vSize`.

Comment: 3) Also in docs for the `index` argument: "vector of column names in dtf that specify the aggregation indices. It could contain only one column name, which results in a treemap without hierarchy." So in your case, that would be `"product"`.

Answer (score 1):

I basically got it working with the following code.

```
library(treemap)
mydata = read.csv("C:\\path\\to\\files\\top_10.csv")

treemap(mydata, #Your data frame object
        index= "PID",  #A list of your categorical variables
        vSize = "Mar",  #This is your quantitative variable
    type="index",        
    palette = "Reds",  #Select your color palette from the RColorBrewer presets or make your own.
        title="TreeMap of Products and Amounts", #Customize your title
        fontsize.title = 14 #Change the font size of the title
        )
```

It only worked after I changed the negative values to positive.  I don't know why all the data points need to be positive.  I'll have to look into that.  Anyway, this is a very nice tool to keep in one's toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, `treemap` does not accept underscore ( _ ) in the column name provided to index, so rename any columns with underscore.